# GPS refresh rate

Tags: android, gps, refresh, rate, garmin

I'm looking for a device to use at amateur karting races in order to display realtime speed and lap timing during my races (about 40 minutes each). I checked if I had a device that could be suitable and hereby request some ideas.

Available devices: iPhone 5 A1428; Garmin Nuvi 40; Samsung S6 Duos G920FD; LG p500h; Bluetooth GPS Adapt Ad-350+.

*A little history*. As per my research, I found that American army (who developed the GPS) limited GPS use to non-military aspect by forcing devices to work within some limits (maximum altitude, not to work with high acceleration rates within two axes, etc.); instead, manufactures noticed that just by limiting to a 1Hz sample (1 locating per second) would make GPS unsuitable for military purposes.

I found that there are devices which operate at 5, 10 and 20Hz (Gamin GLO, QSTARZ 818XT) which makes me consider these update rates are not illegal, but unfortunately these devices are not available at my local market. For sure, it's important to notice that mobile devices usually have battery issues when operating with GPS on, but I'm considering to use it for less than one hour only (total racing duration, briefing included).

So, after all above: is there a way to make any of my devices to work on a higher location sampling?

See attached picture (found at http://www.kartbuzz.com.br/telemetria-no-kart-amador) for different sampling impacts: [GPS 1Hz and 10Hz comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7jMG.jpg)

Comment: Sample rate is based on hardware and nothing you can do to change that in software

Comment: Wouldn't sample rate be related to the firmware instead of the hardware itself? For sure an increase of temperature would occur, but I guess hardware would remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

According to GSM Arena (https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s6_duos-7377.php) your Samsung S6 Duos is capable of measuring linear and angular acceleration (with built-in accelerometer and gyros). These sensors typically support higher sampling rates than 1Hz. By means of a filter (I would search for "Kalman Filtering") you could process the data generated by your GPS, accelerometers and gyros, and get accurate position measurements with sampling rates higher than 1Hz.
I hope this helps.